# padding still exists when height and width of span are 0 with only padding-left set to 20px

Tags: html, css

Here is my setup:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
span {
  padding-left: 25px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

I have span tag with settings of `box-sizing:border-box` and `padding-left:25px`. When this span tag does not have any values in it, its `height` and `width` are `0`. So I expect the span tag not to display on the web page. However, It is still there, I think it is because of the padding-left. But I only set the `padding-left` so it still does not have height to display. But as you can see in jsfiddle, the padding displays on the webpage......

Why does it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `box-sizing` property only [applies to elements that accept a width or height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing). By default, a `span` element is a non-replaced inline element, which means that the `width` property doesn't apply to it, thus the `box-sizing` property doesn't apply to it either.

For reference, here is a relevant link to the specification regarding which elements the `box-sizing` property applies to:

> [**3. Box Model addition - 3.1. box-sizing property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ui-3/#propdef-box-sizing)
>
> Applies to: all elements that accept `width` or `height`

Here is the relevant quote and link to the specification regarding the `width` property and non-replaced inline elements:

> [**10.2 Content width: the 'width' property**](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#the-width-property)
>
> This property [width] does not apply to non-replaced inline elements. The content width of a non-replaced inline element's boxes is that of the rendered content within them (before any relative offset of children). Recall that inline boxes flow into line boxes. The width of line boxes is given by the their containing block, but may be shorted by the presence of floats.

Therefore, if you change the `display` property of the `span` element to `inline-block` or `block`, then the element won't appear (as you seem to be expecting):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
span {
  padding-left: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response, I understand that. Can I ask one thing? um is it normal behaviour that the padding of span tag displays even if it does not have value which means content's height and width are 0?

Comment: since only the padding-left is set

Comment: @kisungTae - Yes, that's normal behavior. In your case a `span` element with content is treated the same way as a `span` element without content. Even with just `padding-left`, it will still show up due to the way padding works in CSS. It doesn't additionally need top/right/bottom padding in order to appear - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7073558/2680216) has a visual demonstration of this. It may be helpful in addition to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer!!

Answer (score 0):

make the span `display:block` or `inline-block` the will remove the extra space.